# Electron mass enhancement: how to change the integral in the energy shift equation from dk' to de?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I am trying to change the integral in this equation for the energy shift due to quasiparticle energy renormalization from being over the momentum space, $d\boldsymbol{k}'$ to being over $d\epsilon$.

Equation 1 (for the energy shift):

$$
\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}} - \mu = \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}}^0 - \mu - \int{\frac{d\boldsymbol{k'}}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{|g_{\boldsymbol{k-k'}}|^2 n_{\boldsymbol{k'}}}{(\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}} - \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k'}})^2 - \omega (\boldsymbol{k} - \boldsymbol{k'})^2}}
$$

I want to change the integral in this equation to this integral:

$$
g^2\int_{-\infty}^{\mu} d\epsilon' N(\epsilon') \frac{1}{(\epsilon' - \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}})^2 - \omega_D^2}
$$

I'm not sure how to go about doing this exactly. The assignment says to achieve this by doing the following:

1. Neglect the momentum dependence of the coupling constant $g$
2. Replacing the phonon frequency by the characteristic scale $\omega_D$ (I'm confused by what's means by characteristic scale here)

I'm still unclear on how to start. First I'd want an expression relating $\boldsymbol{k}$ and $\epsilon$, which I think I'm meant to use $\epsilon(\boldsymbol{k}) = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} - \int_{k' < k_F} \frac{d\boldsymbol{k'}}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{4 \pi e^2}{|\boldsymbol{k} - \boldsymbol{k'}|^2}$ but I'm not sure to be honest. Could someone please confirm or tell if I'm headed in the wrong direction?

Thank you

Comment: Okay, never mind that last bit, I think I'm meant to use $\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}} = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$

Comment: yeah, energy and wavevector are related through the dispersion model. Looks like you’re going with the free-electron approximation.

Comment: Okay, so taking the free electron energy, I get $d\boldsymbol{k} = \frac{m}{\hbar^2 k} d\epsilon$, which, putting into the integral from equation 1 gives me: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\mu} \frac{m}{\hbar^2 k} d\epsilon \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{g^2 n_{\boldsymbol{k'}}}{(\epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}} - \epsilon_{\boldsymbol{k'}})^2 - \omega_D(\boldsymbol{k} - \boldsymbol{k'})^2} $$,  I'm not sure where to go from here